# New line in a verbatim string literal

Tags: c#, verbatim-string

I have a string as follows:

```
string example = @"string str = ""forty-two"";
char pad = '*';
```

the output is in a single line as follows:

```
string str = "forty-two"; char pad = '*';
```

I need the output as follows:

```
string str = "forty-two"; 
char pad = '*';
```

How can I insert newline before 'char pad' in this verbatim string literal

Comment: I'm kind of missing a `"` in your source. Also, how exactly are you outputting it? On a webpage?

Comment: yes, for example in a label

Comment: HTML does per standard not care about whitespace, this is probably why you don't saw the expected result.

Comment: @A.F.M.GolamKibria you can use interpolation within the verbatim string `string example = $@"string str = ""forty-two"";{("\n")}char pad = '*';";`
Here is a [code snippet](https://rextester.com/HAMA17623)

Answer (score 15):

In a verbatim string literal, apart from two double quotes all the escape characters are interpreted verbatim, so if you want a two-line string you have to manually write it in two lines:

```
string example = @"string str = ""forty-two"";
char pad = '*';";

Console.WriteLine(example); // string str = "forty-two";
                            // char pad = '*';
```

From [msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-does-an-before-the-start-of-a-string-literal-mean.aspx):

> A string literal such as @"c:\Foo" is called a verbatim string
>   literal. It basically means, "don't apply any interpretations to
>   characters until the next quote character is reached". So, a verbatim
>   string literal can contain backslashes (without them being doubled-up)
>   and even line separators. To get a double-quote (") within a verbatim
>   literal, you need to just double it, e.g. @"My name is ""Jon"""
>   represents the string My name is "Jon". Verbatim string literals which
>   contain line separators will also contain the white-space at the start
>   of the line, so I tend not to use them in cases where the white-space
>   matters. They're very handy for including XML or SQL in your source
>   code though, and another typical use (which doesn't need line
>   separators) is for specifying a file system path.
>
> It's worth noting that it doesn't affect the string itself in any way:
>   a string specified as a verbatim string literal is exactly the same as
>   a string specified as a normal string literal with appropriate
>   escaping. The debugger will sometimes choose to display a string as a
>   verbatim string literal - this is solely for ease of viewing the
>   string's contents without worrying about escaping.
>
> [Author: Jon Skeet]

Comment: I gathered from the OP that they knew that, but their complaint was that they got the output on one line instead.

Comment: The output is on the same line.